# how to get data in jquery append and prepend from an xhtml page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I was trying to load more than one html/xhtml/xml pages into a webpage. this is the method i am following

This is my base page

```
<html>
    <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">



    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var indexup = 4;
    var indexdown = 4;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
        console.log($(window).scrollTop()+ " <><><>  " + $(window).height()+"  ===   "+$(document).height());
       // downscroll code
       var total = $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();
       var diff = Math.abs(total-$(document).height());

        if(diff<=2) {

     //  alert("bottom!");
       indexdown = indexdown+1;
       if(indexdown>7)
       {
           alert("This is the last page")
       }
       else
       {
       appendNext(indexdown);
        }
   }

   } else {
      // upscroll code
     if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0)
                {
                    console.log($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()+"  ===   "+$(document).height());
                   //  alert('Scrolled to Page Top');
                     indexup = indexup-1;
                     if(indexup==0)
                     {
                       alert('This is the first page');  
                     }
                     else
                     {
                       appendPrevious(indexup);  
                     }

                 }

   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});        

                function appendNext(index)
                {
                $.get("html/01.PAGE."+index+".html", function (data) {
                    $("#appendToThis").append(data);
                });

                }

                function appendPrevious(index)
                {
                $.get("html/01.PAGE."+index+".html", function (data) {

                    var old_height = $(document).height();  //store document height before modifications
                    var old_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                    $("#appendToThis").prepend(data);
                    $(document).scrollTop(old_scroll + $(document).height() - old_height); //restore "scroll position"

                });

                }



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="loadDiv">

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

$("#loadDiv").load("xhtml/01.PAGE.4.html");
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is working fine as expected. I am loading 01.PAGE.4.html first, 01.PAGE.5.html is appended after the `loadDiv` and 01.PAGE.3.html is prepended.

But actually those 01.PAGE.4.html is 01.PAGE.4.xhtml.

I changed the extentions from xhtml to html for testing and found that the jquery can load xhtml codes, but it cannot append or prepend the same.

That is when i tried to re-run the code as xhtml the code gave me this error

`uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'ownerdocument' of null jquery` when checked the console,

[image]

here is my doubt how to get the value from `#Document`

When i logged it out it has the entire page data, but i dont know how to append or prepend it with jquery. But even for the xhtml page load function of jquery is working. Somebody please help

how to get data from `#Document` for jquery append  and prepend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.get ("xhtml/01.PAGE.xhtml", function (data)
{
     $("#appendToThis").html($(data).children());
}, 'xml');
```

Try this. Refer https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ for more details.

Comment: almost, i edited it to  $.get("xhtml/01.GE."+index+".xhtml", function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var old_height = $(document).height();  //store document height before modifications
                    var old_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                     $("#appendToThis").append($(data).children());
                     
                // $(document).scrollTop(old_scroll); //restore "scroll position"

                   //    $("#appendToThis").append(data);
                }, 'xml');